# How to make ASP.NET Core MVC application get and display product entities with byte arrays from SQL Server database faster?

Tags: c#, arrays, image, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have made my website accessible here if you want to see the waiting: https://autopoint.store/

When you go to `Products`, it will take you about 2-3 minutes to get all the products from the database and load them. Can you guys help me make it load faster?

This is my entity:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}    

[Table("Products")]
public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public string typeOfProduct { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public byte[] image { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how I get them (they are in switch for the categories):

```
public List<Product> getProducts(string filter)
{
        switch (filter)
        {
            case "Engine parts":
                return context.Products.Where(x => x.typeOfProduct.Equals("Engine parts")).ToList();

            case "Gear boxes":
                return context.Products.Where(x => x.typeOfProduct.Equals("Gear boxes")).ToList();

            case "Car interior":
                return context.Products.Where(x => x.typeOfProduct.Equals("Car interior")).ToList();

            case "Race chips":
                return context.Products.Where(x => x.typeOfProduct.Equals("Chip tuning")).ToList();

            case "Exhaust system":
                return context.Products.Where(x => x.typeOfProduct.Equals("Exhaust system")).ToList();

            default:
                return context.Products.ToList();

        }
}
```

And here is how I display the image:

```
<img style="" class="img-fluid" src="data:image/png;base64,@(Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(item.image)))" alt="~/img/product/default_photo.png">
```

Can you give me some advise on how to make the loading faster?

Comment: **Don't** use `data:` URIs to represent (_large-ish_) images in webpages - _yikes, that's bad_. RDBMS are not really intended for storing things like images for websites: use a web-_native object-store like Azure Blobs or Amazon S3 - or your webserver's local filesystem for that.

Comment: Can i integrate two databases to work in single application? Im asking cause i haven't done such thing before.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "integrate two databases" - or how that's relevant to the problem of storing and serving images in a website.